# Как сфокусировать камеру на объекте в Corona sdk?

Tags: android, lua, coronasdk

[Вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8556105/5000805) был задан на англоязычном SO несколько лет назад. За это время ссылки устарели, так что я задам его снова.
Как сделать фокус на определенном объекте в Corona sdk?

[image: схема]

*можете заодно подсказать, как управлять объектом кнопками?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Эта библиотека называется *perspective.lua*. Её можно отыскать на гитхабе.